# Emacs Lisp comment conventions

Tags: elisp, comment

The Emacs Lisp Reference Manual's [Appendix D.7](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Comment-Tips.html) mentions some comment tips:

- Single semicolons (`;`) should be used for inline comments.
- Double semicolons (`;;`) should be used for line comments.
- Triple semicolons (`;;;`) should be used for "comments which should be considered a heading by Outline minor mode".
- Quadruple semicolons (`;;;;`) should be used for headings of major sections of a program.

The single and double semicolon use cases are clear, but there does not seem to be a sharp delineation between triple and quadruple semicolons.

In particular, the standard documentation for Emacs packages provided by `auto-insert` uses triple semicolons, never quadruple semicolons, even for the highest-level headings like file name and major sections. See example below:

```
;;; test.el --- A test file.                         -*- lexical-binding: t; -*-

;; Copyright (C) 2016

;; Author:  John Smith
;; Keywords: 

;; This program is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify
;; it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by
;; the Free Software Foundation, either version 3 of the License, or
;; (at your option) any later version.

;; This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
;; but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
;; MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
;; GNU General Public License for more details.

;; You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License
;; along with this program.  If not, see <http://www.gnu.org/licenses/>.

;;; Commentary:

;; 

;;; Code:



(provide 'test)
;;; test.el ends here
```

What are the best practices for triple and quadruple semicolons?

### Update

Thanks to [Stefan's answer](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/21061/10269), I have filed a bug report and made the following suggestion:

> I suggest that the description for three semicolons be changed to:
>
> ```
> Comments that start with three semicolons, ‘;;;’, are considered
> top-level headings by Outline minor mode.
>
> Four or more semicolons can be used as subheadings in hierarchical
> fashion. E.g.
>
> ;;; Main heading
> ;;;; Sub heading
> ;;;;; Sub sub heading
> ;;;; Another sub heading
> ;;; Next main heading
>
> These comments should be used to break Emacs Lisp code into sections.
> ```
>
> A link to "Outline minor mode" in the Emacs manual would be useful:
>   https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Outline-Mode.html
>
> The section for four semicolons can be elided.

Comment: Look through the Emacs sources (`grep -r '^;;;; ' lisp`) for inspiration.

Comment: @sds that turns up a few non-standard applications of ;;;; in the canonical sources ;)

Comment: That's what I meant - this 4 semicolon recommendation cannot be taken too seriously, OTOH, one should also look at the file timestamp - these non-standard things could be obsolete.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Actually, 3-and-more semi-colons stand for headings, where the more semi-colons you put the deeper the nesting of the heading.  So it should look like

```
;;; Main heading
;;;; Sub heading
;;;;; Sub sub heading
;;;; Another sub heading
;;; Next main heading
```

Comment: That seems to be the common practice, but differs from the conventions listed in the Elisp manual linked in the question. Is that a bug in the manual?

Comment: It's not just a question of practice.  That's how `emacs-lisp-mode` configures `outline-minor-mode`.  I suggest you report this as a documentation bug (I think the doc is unclear more than wrong, but the end result is the same).

Comment: I have sent a bug report, and offered a suggestion to change the documentation to something else. I see that I can get the TexInfo source for the manual; is there a repository that I can clone and make a pull request against?

Comment: @TianxiangXiong: Of course, the doc is part of Emacs's source code, so you can clone `git://git.sv.gnu.org/emacs.git` and then send a patch via `M-x report-emacs-bug`.

Comment: For reference, [here are the Common Lisp conventions](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/lw51/CLHS/Body/02_ddbe.htm). If Emacs Lisp really uses 3 semicolons for a heading but then 4 semicolons for a less prominent heading, that seems illogical and contrary to what I've seen in CL and other lisps. Maybe it's simply a better fit for org-mode style headings so they went with it for elisp too.

Comment: @Lassi: Actually, Elisp's convention is very close to the one you reference.  The only difference is that top-level comments should also use `;;` rather than `;;;` (they'll still be indented to column 0 since they're at toplevel), and this frees up `;;;` for use as a heading, so it can be seen as an optimization of CLHS's convention which removes one `;` from headings (CLHS convention doesn't mention what happens with `;;;;;` but it would make sense to treat it as a subheading).

Comment: @Stefan The idea of the CL/traditional lisp convention is that more semicolons = more prominent. ELisp is almost like that too, but `;;;` and `;;;;` are swapped from that standpoint :)

Comment: Does every heading should start with capital letter? 
If so maybe we should add it to "Emacs Lisp Reference Manual"